# How do I typeset continued fractions in Pringsheim's concise notation?

Tags: fractions, inline

I would like to obtain the following formatting so as to write continued fractions in my equations without wasting vertical space.

[image: Sample of notation]

What I need is one command named `\cFrac` which writes one fraction and at the same time which adds vertical rules at the right of the denominator and at the left of the numerator. With this command, the preceding output will be typed : `A + \cFrac{B}{C} + \cFrac{D}{E}`.

The sizes of the rules must be adapted to the size of the denominator and the numerator.

(*Added by Andrew Stacey*: The duplicate question [How to typeset a continued fraction in the following style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73871/86) has an example from the recent literature together with links to more information.)

Comment: Just to know: where is this notation come from?

Comment: I've just read this in one french book and I don't know who originally used it. I think this notation is very efficient.

Comment: small heads up: if you're using `amsmath`, the command `\cfrac` is defined there with a display-oriented style of output.  (also `\lcfrac` and `\rcfrac`.)  in that case, you might want to use another name, perhaps `\tcfrac`.

Comment: I know that, that's why I proposed `\cFrac`. Indeed, I've decided to use `\singleContFrac`.

Comment: According to the package that tohecz found, the notation goes back to Maxwell.

Comment: But apparently Maxwell used it for something else and it was Pringsheim who introduced it for continued fractions.

Comment: In the book "A history of mathematical notations", volume II, p. 56 (1929 edition), Florian Cajori attributes the notation to Alfred Pringsheim.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A couple of versions, you probably need to fiddle with the spacing to get exactly what you need but:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\cFrac#1#2{%
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}\\%
\hline\multicolumn{1}{|c}{#2}\end{array}}

\def\cFracB#1#2{%
\vcenter{\hbox{\strut$#1$\,\vrule}\hrule\hbox{\strut\vrule\,$#2$}}}

\begin{document}

$ A + \cFrac{B}{C} + \cFrac{D}{E}$.

$ A + \cFracB{B}{C} + \cFracB{D}{E}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's look great !

Comment: There's a package for this of course, see my answer.

Comment: I would say that when typeset as part of a line, all the verticals should be the same height (unless one is excessively outsized).  For bonus points, how would you do that?

Comment: btw, have you tried what happens with `\cFrac{B}{\frac{n^6}{n+5}}` ?

Comment: @tohecz I just tried it, fractions are smaller in array cells is that what you mean? Could change the definition to `\displaystyle#2` (and same for `#1`) if that is not desired.

Comment: For me, the fraction line is not centered vertically. Sorry, I could have provided a better one: `$ A + \cFrac{B}{\frac{n^6}{n+5}} + \cFrac{D}{E} $`

Comment: Oh yes there is (using tabular) no alignment on the horizontal line the table as a whole is vertically centred. If you need the horizontal lines to be at the same level and you have varying size entries then a different technique would be needed.

Answer (score 20):

I'm sure you are looking for the [`holtpolt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/holtpolt) package and its command `\polter`, like in the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{holtpolt}

\begin{document}

\[
a_0+\polter{1}{a_1}+\polter{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\polter{1}{a_n}+\cdots
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]