# uncommon form of continued-fraction expression

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I have a copy of the text from the book to do. But I have been working in latex for a month and I have a problem with remaking these continued fractions.

[image: Here is an example]

My code is looking like this:

```
\[
\frac{n_{0}}{n_{1}}=q_{1}+\frac{1}{q_{2}+\frac{1}{q_{3}+\frac{1}{q_4+\ddots}}} & \\
& +\frac{1}{q_{k-1}+\frac{1}{q_{k}}.}
\]

\begin{equation*}
3,14159=3+\frac{1}{7+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{15+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{25+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{7+\frac{1}{4}.}}}}}}}
\end{equation*}
```

Do you know how to do it under and how to align it to the left side?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se

Comment: (it's better if you post the screenshot of the current code output.) Looks like you want some `\phantom` and `\mathrlap`.

Comment: Quite similar to [How to typeset a continued fraction in the following format? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73195/how-to-typeset-a-continued-fraction-in-the-following-format) , although the alignment is slightly different (the + is aligned with the vinculum instead of the numerator)

Comment: Not an answer, but a question: from which book is it?  It looks like a book from "Mała Biblioteczka Matematyczna".

Answer (score 10):

An `array` with a bit of visual formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3][1-4]
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\md}[2][1.45]{\mathbin{\raisebox{-#1ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\displaystyle#2$}}}
\md{\frac{n_0}{n_1}=q_1+{}}
\begin{array}[t]{ *{9}{>{\displaystyle{\mathstrut}}c<{{}}} }
1 \\
\cline{1-3}
\md{q_2} & \md{+}   & 1 \\
\cline{3-5}
         &          & \md{q_3} & \md{+} & 1 \\
\cline{5-7}
         &          &          &        & \md{q_4} & \md{+} & \md[3]{\ddots} \\
&&&&&&& \md{+} & 1 \\
\cline{9-9}
&&&&&&&   & q_{k-1} + \cfrac{1}{q_k}
\end{array}
\]
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\md}[2][1.45]{\mathbin{\raisebox{-#1ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\displaystyle#2$}}}
\md{3{,}14159=3+{}}
\begin{array}[t]{ *{13}{>{\displaystyle{\mathstrut}}c<{{}}} }
1 \\
\cline{1-3}
\md{7} & \md{+} & 1 \\
\cline{3-5}
&& \md{15} & \md{+} & 1 \\
\cline{5-7}
&&&& \md{1} & \md{+} & 1 \\
\cline{7-9}
&&&&&& \md{25} & \md{+} & 1 \\
\cline{9-11}
&&&&&&&& \md{1} & \md{+} & 1 \\
\cline{11-13}
&&&&&&&&&& 7 & + & \cfrac{1}{4}
\end{array}
\]
\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, happy Christmas :)

Answer (score 8):

I'm sure there are easier ways, but this seems to get it done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\mywd{35pt}
\begin{document}
\[
  \frac{n_0}{n_1} = q_1 + \dfrac{\makebox[\mywd][l]{$1$}}
  {\makebox[\mywd][l]{$q_2 + \dfrac{\makebox[\mywd][l]{$1$}}
  {\makebox[\mywd][l]{$q_3 + \dfrac{\makebox[\mywd][l]{$1$}}
  {\makebox[\mywd][l]{$q_4 + 
   \raisebox{-6pt}{$\ddots$}
   \raisebox{-12pt}{+$\dfrac{\makebox[\mywd][l]{$1\kern30pt$}}
  {q_{k-1} + \dfrac{1}
  {q_k}}$}$}}$}}$}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Plus a slight point that OP 's dots are less sloped than ddots, but probably it doesn't matter. • that the  `+`  right after the `ddots` is interpreted as unary makes the spacing bad however.

Comment: To my eye the 1s are a little close to the horizontal line above them.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, happy Christmas :)

Comment: @Cloudy Likewise, a merry and blessed Christmas to you and yours!

Comment: @graffe That is a function of the font.  For example, change to `\usepackage{newpxmath}` and see that dimension larger than before.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The normal font kern cannot be inserted here, since the `1` is hidden inside the fraction. Adding a `\strut` is therefore necessary. (Newpxmath solves the problem by increasing `\fontdimen11`, the minimum distance below the fraction rule, which seems less than ideal to me.)

Comment: @renkema Thank you for the clarification...and Merry Christmas to you!

Answer (score 7):

The hardest part about this exercise is getting the spacing right.

First, you will want to align the `1` above the `q_i`. For this, you will need measure the width of every `q_i` and place the `1` manually. A helper macro is convenient:

```
\def\leftfrac#1#2#3#4{\frac % {#1} {#2#3#4}
  {\setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle#2$}
    \hbox to\wd0{\hfil$\displaystyle#1$\hfil}\hfill}
  {\displaystyle#2#3#4}}

\[ \leftfrac 1 {q_i} + 1 \]
```

[image: example 1]

The next step is continuing the fraction without extending the rule. This is the trickiest part, because we want to preserve both the spacing between the rule and the `1` and the proper binary spacing around the `+`, while retaining the overall width and height of the fraction.

We solve this problem by following each fraction by two skips, both equalling the width of the part after `q_i`, but the first negative and the second positive. Then, inside the continued fraction, if we can somehow move out the second skip and place it behind the fraction, we should have all we need.

Expanding the previous macro:

```
\def\leftfrac#1#2#3#4{% #1 \over #2 #3 #4
  % measure partial and full denominator
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle#2$}
  \setbox2=\hbox{$\displaystyle#2#3#4$}
  \frac
    % a strut in the numerator ensures proper spacing
    {\hbox to\wd0{\hfil
      $\displaystyle
      \strut #1 $
      \hfil} \hfill}
    % move the last skip of the denominator out of the fraction
    {\displaystyle#2#3#4
      \dimen0=\lastskip \unskip
      \expandafter\egroup
        \expandafter\hskip
          \the\dimen0
      \bgroup}
  % two opposite skips (will cancel unless interfered with)
  \hskip\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2
  \hskip\dimexpr\wd2-\wd0 \relax
}

\[
  \leftfrac 1 {q_1} +
    {\leftfrac 1 {q_2} + 
       {\leftfrac 1 {q_3} + 1}
    } .
\]
```

[image: example 2]

I have placed a dot in the example to show you the horizontal width is the total width of all fractions. Note that the `\strut` is essential to get the proper vertical spacing around the ones.

Now as a final step, add the diagonal dots and the lower-right fraction. We have to measure the latter first; then we can use the fact that our new `\leftfrac` moves the last skip out of its fourth argument:

```
\[ \frac {n_0}{n_1} = q_1 +
   \leftfrac 1 {q_2} +
      {\leftfrac 1 {q_3} +
         {\leftfrac 1 {q_4} +
            { % lower the ddots a bit
              \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle\ddots$}
              \lower5pt\box0
              % measure the lower-right fraction
              \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle
                {} + \leftfrac 1 {q_{k-1}} + {\frac {\strut1}{q_k}}$}
              \lower7pt\copy0
              % give two skips for \leftfrac to shift
              \hskip-\wd0
              \hskip+\wd0
            }
         }
      }
\]
```

This gives you your equation in the form you requested:

[image: example 3]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, happy Christmas :)

Comment: Thank you! I have to say this is a beautiful way of typesetting continued fractions, I was quite glad to figure it out.