# Continued fractions - Minimize the horizontal rules

Tags: fractions

Is there an easy way to display continued fractions like in the picture above?

If you have one complicated solution, it is also ok because I will automatize the building of such outputs.

[image]

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627853/uncommon-form-of-continued-fraction-expression?rq=1)

Comment: Yes it is. I close my question as to be duplicated. Thanks for this.