# How to typeset a continued fraction in the following style?

Tags: fractions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I typeset continued fractions in Pringsheim's concise notation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68190)

How to type a continued fraction in *displaystyle* as shown below?

[image]

Source: Fischler, Stéfane, [*Irrationalité de valeurs de zêta (d' après Apéry, Rivoal, …)*, Séminaire Bourbaki 2002-2003, exposé nº 910 (nov. 2002), Astérisque 294 (2004), 27-62](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~fischler/bourbaki.pdf)

A similar but not quite equal style is the following one due to Alfred Pringsheim adapted from [this](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_continue#Notations) entry of the Wikipedia:

[image]

which was obtained with

```
\[
\zeta (3) = \frac{6\mid }{\mid 5}
           -\frac{1\mid }{\mid 117}
           -\frac{64\mid }{\mid 535}
           -\cdots -\frac{n^{6}\mid }{\mid 34n^{3}+51n^{2}+27n+5}
           -\cdots .
\]
```

---

ADDED. By adapting David Carlisle's code in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68196/1862) answer to the question "[How do I typeset continued fractions in Pringsheim's concise notation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68190/continued-fraction-in-inline-equations)" pointed to in the Jake's comment I was finally able to type

[image]

I used

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\cFrac#1#2{%
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}\\%
\hline\multicolumn{1}{|c}{#2}\end{array}}
```

together with

```
\[
\zeta (3) = \cFrac{6 }{5}
           -\cFrac{1}{117}
           -\frac{64}{535}
           -\cdots 
           -\cFrac{n^{6}}{34n^{3}+51n^{2}+27n+5} 
           -\cdots .
\]
```

So this question can be considered as a duplicate of the question mentioned above. Thanks to all!

Comment: it's not necessary for the visible form of such a structure to be different in-line or in a display.  this should work the same in either environment.

Comment: *Note 1.* `\frac{64}{535}` should be replaced with `\cFrac{64}{535}`.

*Note 2.* It looks better with thick spaces `\;` between  fractions: `\def\cFrac#1#2{%
\;\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\multicolumn{1}{c|}{#1}\\%
\hline\multicolumn{1}{|c}{#2}\end{array}\;}`